# New to OpenGL - how to compile?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, import, g++

I have a file with the following imports:

```
// Include standard headers
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>

// Include GLEW
#include <GL/glew.h>

// Include GLFW
#include <glfw3.h>
GLFWwindow* window;

// Include GLM
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/quaternion.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/quaternion.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/euler_angles.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/norm.hpp>
using namespace glm;

// Include AntTweakBar
#include <AntTweakBar.h>


#include <common/shader.hpp>
#include <common/texture.hpp>
#include <common/controls.hpp>
#include <common/objloader.hpp>
#include <common/vboindexer.hpp>
#include <common/quaternion_utils.hpp> // See quaternion_utils.cpp for RotationBetweenVectors, LookAt and RotateTowards
```

However, when I try to compile it with

```
g++ -lglut -lGLU -lGL rotatetest.cpp -o hello.o
```

I get the following errors:

```
rotatetest.cpp:7:23: error: GLUT/glew.h: No such file or directory
rotatetest.cpp:10:19: error: glfw3.h: No such file or directory
rotatetest.cpp:14:23: error: glm/glm.hpp: No such file or directory
rotatetest.cpp:15:40: error: glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp: No such file or directory
rotatetest.cpp:16:34: error: glm/gtc/quaternion.hpp: No such file or directory
rotatetest.cpp:17:34: error: glm/gtx/quaternion.hpp: No such file or directory
rotatetest.cpp:18:36: error: glm/gtx/euler_angles.hpp: No such file or directory
rotatetest.cpp:19:28: error: glm/gtx/norm.hpp: No such file or directory
rotatetest.cpp:23:25: error: AntTweakBar.h: No such file or directory
```

I know this code works because a) it's from a tutorial and b) I can successfully run it when it is part of an XCode project, just not as a standalone file.

I am on Mac OS X 10.8.5. Can anyone suggest to me how I can compile this?

Answer (score 0):

The include<> directives in your file ask for OpenGL-related headers in your system include directory. g++ on the command line may be using a different system include directory than XCode is.
Make sure that the extra OpenGL headers (GLFW, GLM, GLUT) are placed in your g++ installation as well.

You probably will also have to do this for the static libraries as well.

Comment: Right, but how exactly do I do this?

Comment: I believe that in OSx, the default system include directory for g++ is /usr/include/. If you don't already have the libraries downloaded (GLUT, GLFW, GLM), download them, and copy the contents of their include folders into /usr/include/.

You also should copy the contents of the lib folder which comes with these packages into /usr/lib/.

Comment: How do I find out where the libraries are? I assume they must be downloaded, since all the code works perfectly when I let Xcode do everything for me through the tutorial. But I'm not sure where they are, since I think they were already installed.

Comment: You can use the `-I` option on the command line to specify additional include directories. You probably had to set up the include directories for Xcode as well. Otherwise, use Spotlight, or the `find` command, to locate the headers. These aren't standard headers, so you installed them. Once you have that problem solved, you'll also have to move the `-l` options for the libraries to the end of the command line.